# Wildcard App ID and Bundle ID naming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have created a wildcard App ID and have some questions about bundle ID validity for my app. I don't have a company; I am publishing under my own name.

1) Would a bundle ID, "MyName.CoolAppName" be valid?

2) Or do I have to write, "com.MyName.CoolAppName" ?

3) Or could I use simply use "CoolAppName" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these are valid, however, there is a reason people usually use a reverse domain naming system for creating App ID's.

The most important thing to remember is every App ID created, by anyone, has to be unique.  So if someone else has already made a 'CoolAppName' App ID, you are going to be out of luck.

Most people use the standard com.companyname.appname because it's easy to read, it's standardized, and it's almost definitely going to be unique.

Naming your App ID in a different fashion isn't going to make a ton of difference, but I'd suggest following the standard.

Comment: To clarify, making the bundle identifier all lowercase is a good idea, because it is less error prone. Bundle identifiers are case-sensitive. If you reference a bundle identifier anywhere, knowing it's all lowercase is much easier than recalling the exact capitalisation.

Answer (score 0):

**All these names are valid, but you should use the second one, because of it is common name notation and it will be unique.**